# Why does Rails keep delete all the record in the table when I only want one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery mobile with Rails, but when I want to delete a specific record from a table, it ends up deleting everything in the table..

```
  <% @item.each do |basket| %>
      <li data-icon="minus" id = "clicker"><a href="#">
        <img src=<%= basket.item.item_media.url%> />
        <h3><%= basket.item.brand %> </h3>
        <p><%= basket.item.short_description %> </p></a>
       <a><%= link_to "Delete From Basket",{:controller => "items", :action => "delete_from_basket", :item_id => basket.item.id}%></a>
      </li><% end %> </ul>
```

Here is my delete_from_basket method.

```
 def delete_from_basket
  random = params[:item_id]
  @item = ConsumerUsersActivebasket.where(:user_id => current_user.id,:item_id => random).first.destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try instead of

```
 <a><%= link_to "Delete From Basket",{:controller => "items", :action => "delete_from_basket", :item_id => basket.item.id}%></a>
```

this

```
 <%=link_to "Delete From Basket", item_delete_from_basket_path(basket.item)%>
```

Try this in the controller:

```
def delete_from_basket
  @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
  if @item.user_id == current_user.id
     @item.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying,PG::Error: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 1

Comment: Yeah, it still ends up deleting all the items in the basket. Is this a Jquery specific issue?

Comment: find the sql in the console and post it

Comment: SQL (0.9ms)  DELETE FROM "consumer_users_active_items" WHERE "consumer_users_active_items"."" = $1  [[nil, nil]]
PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...active_items" WHERE "consumer_users_active_items"."" = $1